# java and actionscript class is not getting mocked

Tags: java, testing, actionscript, mockito, powermock

I am trying to write a moct test for java controller. This is working fine when I am running this as a junit but this getting failed when i am running in build.

Here is my test class.

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)

public class myTestClass  {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    MyActionScript myActionScript; // It is failing here

    @Mock
    MyBaseClass myBaseClass;  // It is failing here


    @InjectMocks
    MyControllerClass myControllerClass;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(MyControllerClass).build();
    }

    @Test
    @PrepareForTest({TestClass.class})
    public void testmyMethod()throws Throwable{
       //SOme code
    }
}
```

Here the problem is as soon as I am trying to mock my actionscript class or myBaseClass this is getting failed.

Here is my controller class

```
@Controller
public class ReportsController extends BaseController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/someurl", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody somePojo methodList(@RequestBody somePojo requestObj) throws Exception {
        somePojo response = (somePojo) this.execute(requestObj,SOME_CONSTANT);
        return response;
    }
}
```

My controller class extending to the some abstract class.

Here i my myBaseClass

```
@Controller
public abstract class myBaseClass extends myActionScript {
    //Some Code and some methods
}
```

Please let me know if you required any thing else.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` and `@InjectMocks` and `@Mock` annotations.

Do You use MyActionScript and MyBaseClass in MyControllerClass?
If yes try this:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class myTestClass  {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    MyActionScript myActionScript; // It is failing here

    @Mock
    MyBaseClass myBaseClass;  // It is failing here

    @InjectMocks
    MyControllerClass myControllerClass;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(MyControllerClass).build();
    }

    @Test
    @PrepareForTest({TestClass.class})
    public void testmyMethod()throws Throwable{
       //SOme code
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. Yes I am extending myBaseClass from actionScript. I did what you suggested. Still getting the same error in maven build. Running com.jpmc.wss.adr.controller.ReportsControllerTest
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.frmwrk.geek.bootstrap.BootstrapServicesInitializer).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Comment: I asked another question where i posted my full log. Please check this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381165/what-is-bootstrap-initilizer-error-in-java?noredirect=1#comment89735469_51381165